# I cannot handle setTimeout properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form only when a field is blurred and when the timer is over.

So here's what I came up with:

```
function adminRefresh() {
    $("input").blur(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', "pink");
        setTimeout(delayedSubmit, 15000);
    });
};

function delayedSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#refresh').attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#refresh').serialize(),
        dataType: 'js',
        success: function(response) {}
    });
}
```

Here's an exemple of my HTML code, when the function is called :

```
<tr>
    <td><p>Téléphone</p></td>
    <td class='float-label'>
        <%= f.input: phone_number, label: false %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Basically, I want the `delayedSubmit` function to be triggered 15 seconds after a field is blurred. However, It keeps being submitted without doing anything.

Any help ? Many thanks.

Comment: When do you call `adminRefresh()`? Given the minimal code example you've shown, then what you've got should work. It would help a lot to see a more complete extract of your code, along with the HTML

Comment: I'll call it when a field is blurred on a type form. I'll edit my code so you can see.

Comment: "I'll call it when a field is blurred on a type form"...eh? $("input").blur 's callback is what's called when the field is blurred. But adminRefresh needs to be called in order to set up that "blur" event handler in the first place. If you call adminRefresh every time an event blurs, then you'll keep adding more and more "blur" event handlers as well. This logic of this is flawed.

Comment: So you call the `adminRefresh()` function on blur of the field? If so that's your problem. You're creating an event handler for an event when that event happens, hence when the event occurs next the event handler fires twice, next time three times, and so on. To fix this, just remove your `adminRefresh()` function and bind the `blur()` handler when the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you've set the `setTimeout` statement.

You've added the `setTimeout` on `blur`, so everytime the field is blurred `setTimeout(delayedSubmit, 15000);` will be executed, and exactly after 15 seconds the form will be submitted.

This can be fixed by adding a condition like:

```
var isHandlerAttached = null;
$("input").blur(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');
    if (isHandlerAttached) {
        clearTimeout(isHandlerAttached);
    }
    isHandlerAttached = setTimeout(delayedSubmit, 15000);
});
```

This will only let the `delayedSubmit` get executed once the field is blurred for at least 15 seconds.

Other than that, there are few more things you should consider:

1. Execute `adminRefresh()` only once. If you'll execute it more than once, then the `blur` handler will be added multiple times, and will execute multiple times as well, which will submit the form more than once.
2. Add a condition to stop submitting the form after it has been submitted. You can do this by using another variable `isFormSubmitted` and setting its initial value to false. Check it inside `delayedSubmit()` function if its false only then execute the function. And set its value to `true` at the end of `delayedSubmit()` function or in success response of ajax, whichever suits you.

Comment: Wow, nice explanation ! Thanks, it's a bit more clear in my head. However, the countdown still not working. I'll try to figure it out what's wrong.

Comment: I made it worked ! I was calling the `delayedSubmit()` function in a wrong way ... 
Thanks again, that was pretty clear !

Comment: Glad it helped. If this is the right answer, you should set it as 'accepted answer'. And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
//made delay 2 seconds so you dont have to wait 20 to test it
var delayDuration = 2000; //in milliseconds

var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
trigger.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('blurred');
    //send request here
  }, delayDuration);
});
```

```html
<input id="trigger" type="text" value="Blur for delay trigger" />
```